# Use Database statement with Variable Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to store a database name in a variable:

```
DECLARE @SQLString  varchar(max)
DECLARE @DBIn  varchar(50)

SET @DBIn ='myDB'
SET @SQLString = 'USE ' + @DBIn 

select @SQLString
EXEC(@SQLString)
```

There are no errors when I execute this code but it does not actually works (the database does not change as it would if I just run a `USE [myDB]`).

Comment: It would change in the scope of the dynamic sql, not outside of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add database name to schema.table name?

```
DECLARE @SQLString  varchar(max)
DECLARE @DBIn  varchar(50)

SET @DBIn ='myDB'
SET @SQLString = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @DBIn + '.dbo.MyTable' 

select @SQLString
EXEC(@SQLString)
```

Comment: George, I get the following error: "Invalid object name 'myDB.dbo.MyTable' "

Comment: That means you don't have table 'MyTable' in the database, I gave it just as example. I've re-read your question, it looks like you want to change database scope, but it is really not needed because you can query every object on same server by using <DBNAME>.<SCHEMANAME>.<OBJECTNAME>

Comment: You are correct. I think what is left is for me to change my username.. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

DB name is changed for the script which is included in @SQLString.
For e.g, below code will work:

```
DECLARE @SQLString  varchar(max)
DECLARE @DBIn  varchar(50)

SET @DBIn ='myDB'
SET @SQLString = 'USE ' + @DBIn+ ' SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.MyTable'

select @SQLString
EXEC(@SQLString)
```